# Excel to PPT Dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba, range, powerpoint

I have VBA code that contains the range Excel to PPT. So my question is how can I set a dynamic range instead of giving the array values here.

the example below code want same in dynamic:-

```
MySlideArray = Array(5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 31)

MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet4.Range("A10:AS69"), Sheet9.Range("Q10:AH69"), Sheet10.Range("A1:AX65"), Sheet11.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet12.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet13.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet14.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet15.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet16.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet17.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet18.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet19.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet20.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet21.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet22.Range("A1:A12"))
```

I have a Report card that contains all the sheets with Excel range, so when I refer the array it should be capture the Report card Range

Ex

[image]

How to build a dynamic range?

ub copiSylwadau()

'PURPOSE: Copy Excel Ranges and Paste them into the Active PowerPoint presentation slides
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim iCounter As Integer

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

```
'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then Exit
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint Presentation is not open, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

On Error GoTo 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
'MyArray = Worksheets("control").Range("rng")
'MsgBox "MyArray"
  MySlideArray = Array(5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 31)

'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
   MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet4.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet9.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet10.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet11.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet12.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet13.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet14.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet15.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet16.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet17.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet18.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet19.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet20.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet21.Range("A1:A12"), Sheet22.Range("A1:A12"))

'Loop through Array data
  For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
    'Copy Excel Range
        MyRangeArray(x).Copy
        'If iCounter = iCounter < 2 Then

```
    'If rCell And Not rCell.Offset(0, 2) Then
        'copy slide template
        'myPresentation.Slides(4).Copy
        'Set obSlide = myPresentation.Slides.Paste(Index:=iCounter)
       ' iCounter = iCounter
      ' End If

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=True)
    Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    Set MySlideArray = myPresentation.Add(myPresentation.Count + 1)

  On Error GoTo 0

  'Center Object
  With myPresentation.PageSetup
    shp.Left = 20
    shp.Top = 70
    shp.Width = 670
     'shp.Height = ppAutoSizeShapeToFitText


End With
```

Next x

'Transfer Complete
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  MsgBox "Cyflwyniad PowerPoint wedi eu greu!"

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you create named ranges directly then refer to those in your code.
Example: use the name "Sheet4Range" to name Sheet4.Range("A10:AS69")
In your code:

```
Sheet4.Range("Sheet4Range")
```

You can make the definition of the actual Sheet4Range range a Dynamic Named Range (DNR). There are many resources to learn how to construct a DNR. Here's one: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html

Comment: Hi Smiley Thanks for your fedback, this case is little differ from others     Sheet Name Visibilty Table Header
Summary TRUE K10:AS69 BU9
KPI Raised TRUE K10:AH69 BU9
KPI Resolved TRUE K10:AX65 BU9
KPI Open TRUE K10:AX65 BU9
Un Assigned FALSE G15:P70 F8
Re Open FALSE G15:P70 F8   am unable to post like a box. so my question is i have a code which will help us to copy paste the data from excel to ppt the range was we mentioned in front page, so it's too complecate to assign the range as you mentioned above. cause we have more then 50 sheets is available when i click .

Comment: What do you use to determine the ranges to use? Are the ranges the same with only the workbook being different? Comment about your code. 'Set PowerPointApp = ..." ' will create an instance of a power point application. Why do you then test to see if you have one?

Comment: Your response in the comment doesn't make much sense to me. Sorry